# Python webserver script won't submit to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, simplehttpserver

In the below script a simple webserver is created and there is a class that should sends `GET` data to a sqlite3 database.

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sqlite3

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()


class DBLoggingHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DBLoggingHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('/home/cron1admin/crazysean/crazysean.db')
    def do_GET(self):
        self.db.execute("INSERT INTO crazysean (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, self.path))
        self.db.commit()
        return super(DBLoggingHandler, self).do_GET()

DBLoggingHandler()
```

The webserver portion of the script works properly.  I am seeing `GET` data in my terminal output.  However, nothing is being written to the crazysean table that I created in the db.  Do you see anything wrong with my script or is it likely something else?

---

Code has been changed to reflect changes that I have made, but it is still not writing to the db.

UPDATED CODE:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sqlite3

PORT = 8000

class DBLoggingHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('/home/cron1admin/crazysean/crazysean.db')
    def do_GET(self):
        self.db.execute("INSERT INTO crazysean (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, self.path))
        self.db.commit()
        return super(DBLoggingHandler, self).do_GET()

Handler = DBLoggingHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You're never doing a `commit()` on the connection.

Comment: First things first: (1) Did you `CREATE TABLE crazysean` somewhere in that database? (2) Is  Are you trying to keep the same database open in this program and also in an editor (the `sqlite3` command-line, a GUI editor, whatever) at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I did create the table already.  Not sure what you mean in question 2, but I send a few requests to the server and then open up the sqlite CLI and try `SELECT * FROM crazysean` and still nothing.  I guess the db is always open, correct? I never close it in the script.  Would this cause issues?

Comment: You've found yourself a real time capsule of state-of-the-1990s-art Python to work on here. :) A few minor bug fixes, and that's all the changes as far back as the revision history goes (2001). It's always extra fun to work with code like this…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do this:

```
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And then you create the handler class and instantiate it.

So, your code doesn't do anything until after "forever". Which is way too long to wait for it.

What you want to do is pass your handler subclass to the server, in place of the base class. Where you have this:

```
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
```

… instead do this:

```
Handler = DBLoggingHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
```

(Or just get rid of the extra line and do `httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), DBLoggingHandler`).)

You will also have to move the definition of your class up to the top of the file.

---

But there's another problem.

Python used to have two different kinds of classes: [new-style and classic](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes). They fixed that years ago in 3.0, but you're still using 2.something.

Normally you can just always use the new-style classes and never worry about the old kind, but every once in a while you run into a class in the stdlib or a third-party library that's still made the old way, and you want to inherit from it. And that's exactly what happened here. So now, sadly, you have to learn about old-style classes.

Among the things old-style classes can't do is `super`. The fix for this is to explicitly call the unbound method of the base class. So, instead of this:

```
super(DBLoggingHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

… you need this:

```
SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

And likewise for the other `super` call.

The way you know this is happening (other than by looking at the base class) is when you get an error message about `classobj` or `instance`. Those two types always mean a classic class is involved somewhere.

---

But wait, there's more.

Whatever idiot told you to put that `self.db = …` stuff in the `__init__` method was an idiot. :)

`SocketServer` handlers are a weird kind of class. Each new request constructs a new instance, and the `__init__` method calls `handle`, which doesn't return until it's time to destroy the whole instance. So, anything you put in the `__init__` after calling the base class won't happen until it's too late.

The simplest thing to do here is probably to make `db` a global variable. All else being equal, globals are bad. But in this case, the alternatives seem to be either overriding functionality from three different classes, or monkeypatching it into the server instance and relying on undocumented details to reach it.

---

Also, you probably want to close the database somewhere. Killing the program without closing the database should never leave it corrupted, but it can mean you lose the last transaction if you time it just wrong.

Since `serve_forever` never returns except by you hitting ctrl-c, you can't just put it after that line; you need a `with` statement (or a `finally`, or an `except BaseException`, or an `atexit`). I don't think `sqlite3.Connection` objects became context managers until a later version of Python, so you'll have to use the `closing` context manager.

---

So:

```
import contextlib
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sqlite3

PORT = 8000

db = sqlite3.connect('/home/cron1admin/crazysean/crazysean.db')

class DBLoggingHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        db.execute("INSERT INTO crazysean (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, self.path))
        db.commit()
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = DBLoggingHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
with contextlib.closing(db):
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Now I get this error `File "server.py", line 9, in __init__
    super(DBLoggingHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

Comment: @Meepl: Give me a sec, I'll explain that.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful. This is all pretty foreign to me, but I'm trying to learn.

Comment: An interesting problem I never would have figured out without your assistance! So a new error has occured: `File "server.py", line 12, in do_GET
    self.db.execute("INSERT INTO crazysean (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
AttributeError: DBLoggingHandler instance has no attribute 'db'`  I am curious why this isn't happening on line 10 where db is first called...

Comment: @Meepl: Well, it shouldn't get an error there, because line 10 is where `self.db` is being _created_. The question is why it's not still there. Hold on a second…

Comment: One more thing: Once you get past that, you're going to have the `super` bug again. You have to make the same fix at the end of `do_GET`, only this time as `return SimpleBlahBlah.do_GET(self)`.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I have tons of research to do...much of this went over my head!

Comment: @Meepl: Honestly, all of this would be easier if you used a modern web framework. Something like `Flask` may look like it has more of a learning curve than `SimpleHTTPServer`, but the fact that it's being regularly updated, used by thousands of people for real business, etc., and wasn't designed in the 90s, means that you don't run into stuff like this; almost everything you have to learn will be useful knowledge instead of archaic trivia.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the final magic words [`db.commit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) :)

```
def do_GET(self):
        self.db.execute("INSERT INTO crazysean (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, self.path))
        self.db.commit()
        return super(DBLoggingHandler, self).do_GET()
```

You have another error and this one is bigger. You're not actually calling your code, just calling `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`.

Full example:

```
class DBLoggingHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('/home/cron1admin/crazysean/crazysean.db')
    def do_GET(self):
        self.db.execute("INSERT INTO crazysean (command, vers, path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.command, self.request_version, self.path))
        self.db.commit()
        return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET()

Handler = DBLoggingHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: So, obviously this is needed and I added it to my script, but it is still not working

Comment: Yes, it is still not writing anything.  I also added `import sqlite3` which I did not have before and still not writing anything.

Comment: Did you just put the class above all of the webserver stuff? Curious how this changes things.  Testing now.

Comment: Not just that, see? I substituted Handler assignment for your actual class implementation.

Comment: Now I get this error `File "server.py", line 9, in __init__
    super(DBLoggingHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example at the top of:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

You need to create a cursor, execute statements through the cursor, then commit the connection.

Comment: You're right, but actually `connection.cursor()` is a shortcut which creates a temporal `cursor` object so is rather convenient to use `connection.execute()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute